# How to capture WM_KEYDOWN event when PRESS TAB in MFC

Tags: mfc

I want to capture WM_KEYDOWN event when PRESS TAB, but looks like I cannot do it. Only WM_KEYUP can be caught when press TAB

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the WM_KEYDOWN event was filter out by the child control as 'TAB' is in the accelerator table.